# Ordering forum answers based on quantity of upvotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a table of answers (tbAnswers). And I have a table which stores who upvotes an answer (tbContentRanking) which has a record for every time an answer has been upvoted.

I'm querying tbAnswers to get answers for each question and I want the answers with the most upvotes (most records in tbContentRanking) to be at the top. If the recordCount in tbContentRanking is tied between answers, I want the most recent answer to win the tie.

Here's the tables:

```
**tbAnswers**
AnswerID   AnswerValue             QuestionID   CreateDateTime
1          This is an answer       15           Sept. 01 2014
2          This is another answer  15           Sept. 03 2014
3          This is yet another     15           Sept. 09 2014
4          Here's an answer        15           Sept. 10 2014

**tbContentRanking**
ContentRankingID     AnswerID   QuestionID   UserID
1                    3          15           10
2                    3          15           101
3                    2          15           30
4                    2          15           3
5                    4          15           23
6                    4          15           42
7                    4          15           4
8                    1          15           6
```

Based on this it would order the result:

```
AnswerID:
4, 3, 2, 1
```

(3 and two are tied but 3 is more recent)

The initial tbAnswers query (qGetAnswers) is REALLY complicated (for other business reasons) so I just want to do a query of queries of the getAnswers, but not sure the how to do this. OR if query of queries isn't the best idea I'm open to others.

Query of Queries:

```
<cfquery name="getAnswersOrder" dbtype="query">
  SELECT *
  FROM qGetAnswers
   (SELECT Count(AnswerID) AS theCount
    FROM tbContentRanking
     WHERE QuestionID = #arguments.questionID#)
  Order By theCount, CreateDateTime
</cfquery>
```

It's something like this but pretty lost about how to construct the query of queries. OR like I said maybe a QoQ isn't even the best option.

Comment: I added a ColdFusion tag to widen your audience.  Query of queries has a lot of limitations.  One of those is that you can't use subqueries.  Even if you could, your syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is the next:

Instead of computing the num. of upvotes using a subquery you could [denormalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) `tbAnswers` table by adding a column named `UpvotesNum`. This means that every upvote action will "touch" two rows:

1. One row in `tbContentRanking` table (because of `INSERT INTO tbContentRanking (AnswerID, ...) VALUES (@AnswerID, ...)`) and
2. Another row in `tbAnswers` table (because of `UPDATE tbAnswers SET UpvotesNum = UpvotesNum + 1 WHERE AnswerID = @AnswerID`.

From this point of view, the problem of showing those answers with the most upvotes becomes trivial:

```
  SELECT ... columns ...
  FROM tblAnswers
  ORDER BY UpvotesNum, CreateDateTime
```

Comment: Yep I considered making an UpVote column but I still needed to know who made the upvotes. Never occurred to me to have two tables, but this is great. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT QuestionID, CreateDateTime, Count(AnswerID) as theCount
FROM tbContentRanking
WHERE QuestionID = #arguments.questionID#
GROUP BY QuestionID, CreateDateTime
ORDER BY Count(AnswerID), CreateDateTime
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a subquery in the original query to accomplish what you are wanting to do.  This works in SQL Server, I don't know about other DBMS's

```
SELECT AnswerValue, QuestionID, CreateDateTime, (SELECT Count(AnswerID)
FROM tbContentRanking WHERE tbContentRanking.QuestionID = tbAnswers.questionid) as theCount
ORDER BY theCount DESC
```

I understand your original query is REALLY complex, but you really need to minimize your calls to the DB  (or QofQ) and this is fairly simple to add.